# Mysql LIMIT statement in .NET TableAdapter query

Tags: .net, mysql, dataset, limit, tableadapter

I am adding the following query to a .NET dataset TableAdapter.

> select * from users ORDER BY RAND()
>   LIMIT 0,10

But the LIMIT word is not recognized as a part of the query and I am unable to proceed further.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL site has a bug report that looks a lot like you problem: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36622. The problem described there is that the wizard gives an error. But, when you just complete the wizard, it does work.